# Meteor - I can’t use ReactiveVar in a blaze helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to initialize a ReactiveVar in my template onCreated method and pass it to an helper:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './record-infos-page.html';
import './record-infos-page.scss';

Template.Record_infos_page.onCreated(function recordInfosPageOnCreated() {
  this.checkedVariablesIds = new ReactiveVar(['HkcEjZjdxbobbNCZc', 'uTmJKTfoWFFfXPMwx']);
  console.log(1, this.checkedVariablesIds.get());
});

Template.Record_infos_page.helpers({
  checkedVariablesIds() {
    const vars = Template.instance().checkedVariablesIds.get();
    console.log(2, vars);
    return vars;
  },
});
```

The console.log results is:

```
1 ['HkcEjZjdxbobbNCZc', 'uTmJKTfoWFFfXPMwx']
2 undefined
```

Why do I have undefined in the helper?

Thanks!

Comment: Since this was resolved in the forums as a simple typo, you should probably delete this as typo issues are off-topic on SO

Comment: For reference, Meteor forum cross post: https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-i-cant-use-reactivevar-in-a-blaze-helper/42536 "My bad, I had another helper in my child template that erased my reactiveVar."

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instance.autorun` to reactively get the changes of the variable within your template:

> You can use this.autorun from an onCreated or onRendered callback to
>   reactively update the DOM or the template instance.

From [Blaze documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun).

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './record-infos-page.html';
import './record-infos-page.scss';

Template.Record_infos_page.onCreated(function() {
  const instance = this;
  instance.autorun(function() {
    if (!instance.checkedVariablesIds) {
      instance.checkedVariablesIds = new ReactiveVar(['HkcEjZjdxbobbNCZc', 'uTmJKTfoWFFfXPMwx']);
      console.log(1, instance.checkedVariablesIds.get());
    }
  });

});

Template.Record_infos_page.helpers({
  checkedVariablesIds() {
    const vars = Template.instance().checkedVariablesIds.get();
    console.log(2, vars);
    return vars;
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes, but my second console log still display `2 undefined`. It should display the content of the reactive var.

Comment: Then please post the whole template plus the html and css file and the packages versions you use to fully reproduce this ptoblem. On my test project this works without any problem.

Comment: Oh ok so it's a good news if it doesn't reproduce for you. I'll investigate deeper thanks ;)